# How can I setup a one-way scp?

Tags: database, linux, ssh, scp, chroot

I am trying to setup a remote host to act as a data sink, i.e. some kind of environment on the remote host, A, which allows users to scp data from their local machine to A but not from A to their local machine.  One account on the remote host uses rssh with scp only and works great including rsa key exchange so that the user can scp data to the remote host without a password.  However, in its current form the user can also scp data from the remote host to their local host and I want to prevent that.  I am aware of the possibility of setting up a chroot jail so that scp is confined to a certain directory on the remote host and that could work but I was looking for an "easier" way if possible because I don't have much experience with setting up a chroot.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off read permissions on the files you care about for the users you don't want to be allowed to read them.